# JavaScript Crashing Chrome (Infinite Recursion )

Tags: javascript

When I run this my browser freezes and crashes but I can't figure out how to fix it. I am new to JavaScript and I need some help.

```
function Start() {

if (Key1 === true) {
    alert ("1")
    Key1 = false
} else if (Key2 === true) {
    alert ("2")
    Key2 = false
} else {
    window.setTimeout(Start, 1000);
    Start()
}

}
```

Comment: An infinite recursion?

Comment: Yeah but i dont know why.

Comment: What would happen if `Key1 = false; Key2 = false;` before you run your function? Try to evaluate it manually as if you were a JS interpreter.

Comment: I know that its running the function Start() a bunch of times but doesnt the timout stop it from doing that?

Comment: you run `Start` it in a timeout **AND** inline directly (see the next line)

Comment: No, `setTimeout(Start, 1000)` means that after 1 second call `Start()`, not just "sleep one second", therefore you don't need to explicitly call `Start()`. Furthermore, even if it did just sleep, recursively calling like that is never a good idea.

Comment: setTimeout does not "pause" javascript - the callback is called asynchronously after the specified interval

Comment: Oh.. I see thank you thought it was just like sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Key1` and `Key2` are not defined, you directly execute the last `else`.

In it, you call `Start()` twice, once, by a direct call, once by a `setTimeout`, so every time you call `Start`, then two more `Start` will be executed.

You have an infinite recursive call that is expanding with time, the browser cannot keep up and crashes.

Comment: actually, due to the nature of the tight recursion, the timeout code would never start :p - the issue is just runaway recursion

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the excess Function Start().

```
function Start() {

if (Key1 === true) {
    alert ("1")
    Key1 = false
} else if (Key2 === true) {
    alert ("2")
    Key2 = false
} else {
    window.setTimeout(Start, 1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case Key1 and Key2 are both false, the code executes the last block, i.e. calls itself and it goes on infinitely resulting in the browser freeze.
If either Key1 or Key2 is true before you invoke the function for the first time, then you will not get into this recursive call.